# Gmail sends legitimate mails from php mail() function to spam folder

Tags: php, email, gmail, spam, spf

I already searched for solutions for this, but none of them resolved my problem. I'm using Google apps also.

Here's a copy of the message received on gmail:

```
Delivered-To: suporte@taskka.com.br
Received: by 10.114.37.166 with SMTP id z6csp286681ldj;
        Tue, 22 Jan 2013 17:22:28 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.236.119.206 with SMTP id n54mr27422481yhh.8.1358904147674;
        Tue, 22 Jan 2013 17:22:27 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <contato@jetcarros.com.br>
Received: from smtp-web3-ctba.kinghost.net (smtp-web3-ctba.kinghost.net. [177.12.170.3])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id h1si4616624anp.108.2013.01.22.17.22.26;
        Tue, 22 Jan 2013 17:22:27 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of contato@jetcarros.com.br designates 177.12.170.3 as permitted sender) client-ip=177.12.170.3;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of contato@jetcarros.com.br designates 177.12.170.3 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=contato@jetcarros.com.br
Received: from smtp-web-ctba.kinghost.net (smtp-web-ctba [127.0.0.1])
       by smtp-web3-ctba.kinghost.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 7C5D58F2AE
       for <suporte@taskka.com.br>; Tue, 22 Jan 2013 23:22:26 -0200 (BRST)
Received: from web593.kinghost.net (unknown [10.27.86.33])
       by smtp-web-ctba.kinghost.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 7BB2BC2DFC6C
       for <suporte@taskka.com.br>; Tue, 22 Jan 2013 23:22:26 -0200 (BRST)
Received: by web593.kinghost.net (Postfix, from userid 850)
       id 77EA6E9B6; Tue, 22 Jan 2013 23:22:26 -0200 (BRST)
To: suporte@taskka.com.br
Subject: test mail
From: contato@jetcarros.com.br
Subject: test mail
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Message-Id: <20130123012226.77EA6E9B6@web593.kinghost.net>
Date: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 23:22:26 -0200 (BRST)

It's a test mail<br/>
Another line<br/>
Yet another line.
```

and the spf on jetcarros.com.br:

> v=spf1 ip4:177.12.170.0/24 a mx a:jetcarros.com.br include:aspmx.googlemail.com ?all

in other cases that i have found people have said that i could fix the problem by setting the 5th param on php mail function to "-f$senderAdderess" but the envelope-from doesn't even appear in any part of the mail as you can see above.

here's my script:

```
    $email_content = implode ( "\n",array ( "It's a test mail", "Another line", "Yet another line.")
    $email_headers = implode ( "\n",array ( "From: contato@jetcarros.com.br", "Subject: test mail","Return-Path:  contato@jetcarros.com.br","MIME-Version: 1.0","Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" ) );  
    mail('suporte@taskka.com.br', 'test mail', nl2br($email_content), $email_headers, "-fcontato@jetcarros.com.br")
```

**Edit:** As the iWizardPro sugest i use DKIM to sign my mail, and after several hours to make it sign correctly i have accomplished it. But my emails keep going on spam folder.

Any help here is welcome.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe Gmail requires DKIM keys to verify the validity of emails.

When I implemented my site's email system, I had to include DKIM keys for Gmail to stop blocking my emails and sending them to SPAM.

Edit:
I believe this site is relevant as you stated that you are using Google Apps: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174124

Comment: I did the steps on that page but my messagens keep going o spam.
I have to add any header to the email?

Comment: ok, i accomplish to add a DKIM signatire on the email using a script i could find at [link](php-dkim.sourceforge.net). The Google Apps DKIM didn't helped at all, i have to generate my own keys. But still going to the spam folder.

Answer (score 1):

Your IP-/domain reputation seems to be wrecked:

- Sender Score: [14 of 100](https://www.senderscore.org/lookup.php?lookup=177.12.169.33)
- McAfee: Red=[High Spam Risk](http://www.mcafee.com/threat-intelligence/ip/default.aspx?ip=177.12.169.33) (Email)

Solution: Send from another IP/domain.

Comment: But that's not the ip it went from. You searched for 177.12.169.33 and the sender was 177.12.170.3

Comment: Oops, sry. Anyway: 177.12.170.3 has a high spam risk, too. Seems as if the network has been abused.